# Typescript save object to server and keep metadata

Tags: angular, typescript, reflect

In an Angular app, I have an object with some metadata on it's properties using `Reflect.defineMetadata()`. I need to save this object on the server and parse it back keeping my metadata. 
`JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` loose this data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending data to server. Try to get the data itself from server. So you use restangular directly fetch that data with an URL. Use window.localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(data));

Use Data by var t= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data')) anywhere in app. Thats how you are supposed to do it.

Replicate same scenario if you want to use APP to send data to server. Handle at server side. Send from server using above way